# Declare class field in one partial class that inherits a class, then initialize it in another

Tags: c#, partial-classes

i have two part of a partial class:

```
public partial class Class1 : AnotherClass
{
   int id;
}

public partial class Class1
{
   public void func()
   {
      //here i need to access the id variable defined in the other part
      id = 1;   //this instruction raise an error "The name 'id' does not exists in the current context"
   }
}
```

How can I access that variable?

Comment: I edited the title to hopefully better convey the real question.

Comment: Your actual problem is, why does the uninitialized variable needs to be declared in another partial (i.e. now it is not partial anymore).

Comment: @Steve sorry I forget the function!

Comment: @MauriceStam I have simplified my real situation

Comment: Is the namespace the same?

Comment: Yes. I my real situation the class is a type of row in a dataset object so it's declared as:
`public partial class TimeReportRow : global::System.Data.DataRow`

Comment: You sure that you have declared the classes in the same namespace??

Answer (score 7):

You can access that field, but you have to **access it in some method/constructor**, you can't directly access it at class level.

```
public partial class Class1
{
   public void SomeMethod()
   {
     id = 1;
   }
}
```

If you are doing Field initialization then its better if you define an overloaded constructor in your partial class and then assign values like:

```
public partial class Class1
{
   public Class1(int id)
   {
     this.id = id;
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the function in the second part of the class. Now I've added that

Comment: @Albirex, Your method signature is wrong, Your should specify return type rather than `function`, it should be something like: `public void func()`. But apart from that it should compile as long as both the classes are defined in a single namespace.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can't tell which statement is first in your example. Initialize your class level variables in the constructor.

```
public partial class Class1
{
   int id;
}

public partial class Class1
{
   //here i need to access the id variable defined in the other part
  public Class1()
  { 
     id = 1; 
  }
}
```